# mail header title wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress

i have a contact form in my wordpress site and its working fine however, I need some modification to the way the mail receive..

In my mail, I see this.

```
WordPress <wordpress@juanbusinessdesign.com>
```

and it looks not nice to me so what I need is to remove "Wordpress" from that header part and it should be or will be replaced with

```
Juan Business Design <wordpress@juanbusinessdesign.com>
```

is there anyway I could make that? im currently searching for that solution over the internet and through wordpress files or wp-mail.php and seems I couldnt find one.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `wp_mail_from_name` filter for this.

```
<?php
add_filter('wp_mail_from_name', 'so17635785_from_name');
function so17635785_from_name($name)
{
    return 'Juan Business Design';
}
```

That will replace the from name on ALL emails from your site, including your contact form if it's done corrrectly.

Answer (score 0):

You got it right, replacing `WordPress <wordpress@juanbusinessdesign.com>` with `Juan Business Design <wordpress@juanbusinessdesign.com>` will work.